# Bootstrap align input field in dl - dt

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to horizontal align this so the input field and text are in the same line?

[image]

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <dl class="row">';
      if($row_list['bestelno'] > 0) { echo '
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Artikel</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">'.$row_list['bestelno'].'</dd>'; }
  echo '

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Omschrijving</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">'.$row_list['omschrijving'].'</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Nieuw aantal</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="input-group form-group has-success-edit has-feedback" id="div_exp_aantal['.$i.']">
      <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="exp_aantal['.$i.']" name="exp_aantal" placeholder="Huidige aantal" value="'.($row_list['aantal_huidig'] - 1).'" onkeyup="validate_edit(this, '.$i.')" onmousemove="validate_edit(this, '.$i.')"><span class="input-group-addon">'.$row_list['eenheid'].' &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" id="exp_aantal_status['.$i.']"></span></span>
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Clean HTML added on request. CSS is standard Bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <dl class="row">

                      <dt class="col-sm-3">Omschrijving</dt>
                      <dd class="col-sm-9">Pallet gebruikt 120x80</dd>

                      <dt class="col-sm-3">Nieuw aantal</dt>
                      <dd class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="input-group form-group has-success-edit has-feedback" id="div_exp_aantal[2]">
                          <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="exp_aantal[2]" name="exp_aantal" placeholder="Huidige aantal" value="35" onkeyup="validate_edit(this, 2)" onmousemove="validate_edit(this, 2)"><span class="input-group-addon">stuk &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" id="exp_aantal_status[2]"></span></span>
                        </div>
                      </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
```

EDIT suggested by Alessio results in
[image]

Comment: Can you please post clean HTML code, without PHP and your CSS?

Comment: Added, css is standard Bootstrap.

Comment: I think you're going the wrong way, semantic wise, with dl/dt/dd to begin with here. That there exists no grouping element for individual dt/dd inside a dl only adds to the problem. Choose an HTML structure that _does_ allow you to group them properly would be my advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *Nieuw aantal* aligned to *35*, you can give:

Add to .col-sm-3 the class "input-aligned":

HTML

```
<dt class="col-sm-3 input-aligned">Nieuw aantal</dt>
```

CSS:

```
.input-aligned {
  line-height:34px;
}
```

It's always better adding custom class to your HTML, since the style you are overriding is coming from Bootstrap.

[Updated codepen here](http://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/OOwyda).

Comment: Here's the codepen with the changed I suggested you: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/OOwyda

Comment: What else did you change besides the CSS?

Comment: Nothing else as you can see, I just import Bootstrap CSS into Codepen, as you said you are using this framework. Do you have any additional CSS?

Comment: I'm checking, are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159810/discussion-between-alessio-and-muiter).

Comment: @Muiter Did you make it?

Comment: I will look to this issue later on Alessio.

Comment: Almost, I have tried an new approach buit I will post an new question with the new problem I am facing.

Comment: Ok, hope I was helpful!